# Chrome downloading file without extension (IE and mozilla does it well)

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to send a msword file to user.

So here is the code which create the outputStream (it's a more than 10 years old application):

```
private PrintWriter parse(long docId) throws BusinessException {
    HttpServletResponse response = get_JessContext().getServletResponse();
    response.setContentType("application/msword");

    PrintWriter out;

    try {
        out = response.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        out = null;
    }
    BufferedReader document = null;
    FileInputStream file = null;
    String docUrl = new String(EMPTY_STRING);
    StringBuffer agenceDoc = new StringBuffer(EMPTY_STRING);
    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;
    String parameter = null;
    InputStreamReader inputStream = null;
    try {

        if (docId == -1) {
            adminService.getDocument(agenceDoc, get_UserAgenceId()
                    .longValue(), getDocNameNormalise());

        } else

        if (docId > 0) {
            adminService.getDocument(agenceDoc, get_UserAgenceId()
                    .longValue(), docId);
        }

        if (docId == -1) {
            if (agenceDoc.toString().equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {

                docUrl = JSPFile.getDocsdir()
                        + JSPFile.getFile(get_JessContext(),
                                getDocNameNormalise());

                file = new FileInputStream(docUrl);
                inputStream = new InputStreamReader(file);
            } else {
                logger.debug("agenceDoc.toString() du document="
                        + agenceDoc.toString());
                inputStream = new InputStreamReader(
                        new StringBufferInputStream(agenceDoc.toString()));
            }
        } else if (docId > 0) {
            inputStream = new InputStreamReader(
                    new StringBufferInputStream(agenceDoc.toString()));
        } else {
            logger.debug(" JSPCourrier : doc_id non valide");
            throw new Exception();
        }
        document = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

        String line = null;
        String lineKeep = null;
        String lineOut = null;
        boolean first = true;
        boolean enteteComplet = true;
        do {
            line = document.readLine();
            if (line != null) {
                if (lineKeep != null) {
                    String lineTemp = lineKeep + line;
                    line = lineTemp;
                    lineKeep = null;
                }
                if (enteteComplet) {

                    startIndex = 0;
                    lineOut = null;
                    first = true;
                    do {
                        if (startIndex != 0) {
                            startIndex += START_SEPARATOR.length();
                        }
                        if (startIndex == 0 && !first)
                            startIndex += START_SEPARATOR.length();
                        startIndex = line.indexOf(START_SEPARATOR,
                                startIndex);
                        if (startIndex != -1) {
                            if (first) {
                                lineOut = line.substring(0, startIndex);
                                first = false;
                            } else {
                                lineOut += line.substring(endIndex
                                        + END_SEPARATOR.length(),
                                        startIndex);
                            }
                            endIndex = line.indexOf(END_SEPARATOR,
                                    startIndex);
                            if (endIndex == -1) {
                                lineKeep = line.substring(startIndex);
                                startIndex = -1;
                            }
                            if (endIndex != -1) {
                                parameter = line.substring(startIndex
                                        + START_SEPARATOR.length(),
                                        endIndex);
                                lineOut += getParametre(parameter);
                            }
                        }
                    } while (startIndex != -1);
                    if (lineOut != null) {
                        if (lineKeep == null) {
                            lineOut += line.substring(endIndex
                                    + END_SEPARATOR.length());
                        }
                    } else {
                        lineOut = line;
                    }

                    out.println(lineOut + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        } while (line != null);
    } catch (BusinessException be) {
        throw be;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (document != null)
            try {
                document.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (file != null)
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return out;
}
```

if I change the contentType, it's fine for IE or Mozilla, they both change extension according to the new content type (even if it's not the good one for the document)

but Chrome.. it doesn't add any extension to the downloaded file and I can't find out why.

for information, the file downloaded is a .rtf file, but has to be read with MS Word.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the filename by adding a Content-Disposition header:

```
response.setContentType("application/msword");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=whatever.rtf");
```

That also will probably look better than the ugly name the browser is likely to generate.

Comment: Wonderful! you solve 2 of my problems in one shot :)
Thanks a lot!

I need to learn about headers ^^